# Como eliminar una string dentro del state, de forma local y en el servidor, de manera efectiva usando React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando borrar una string en concreto dentro de un array que forma parte del estado de mi componente, una vez que se pulsa un botón. Lo logro hacer de forma local (en el estado del componente de React) pero mi código hace algo inesperado cuando lo hago también en el servidor (estoy utilizando una API REST).

El nombre del item y su botón de borrar correspondiente se renderizan condicionalmente atendiendo a como esté en ese momento `items_local`

```
state = {
items_local: [
   "item numero 1", "item numero 2", "item numero 3"
]}

<div className="items-container">
        {this.state.items_local.map((item, i) =>
          <div>
            <li key={i} data-id={item.id}>{item.name}
              <button onClick={this.deleteTask.bind(this, item.id)}>Borrar</button>
            </li>
          </div>
        )}
```

Cuando le doy a borrar el `"item numero 1"` correctamente se borra. Sin embargo en el servidor (en mi base de datos local) se borra el `"item numero 3"`. 
Sospecho que es por la manera en cómo estoy utilizando el `id`

```js
deleteTask = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      items_local: this.state.items_local.filter(function (item) {
        return item.id !== id
      })
    });
   
    let taskToDelete = id;
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/api/task/${this.state.items_local[taskToDelete].idApi}`)
            .then(() => console.log('task eliminada en backend'))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
```

Con ese código de forma local si borra correctamente el item pinchado, pero borra uno diferente en el servidor. Sospecho que es por que cada vez que se añade un item se hace de esta manera:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  items_local: [{ "name": nombreTask, "id": itemsCounter, idApi: "" }, ...prevState.items_local]
}))
```

Quizás debería hacerlo al revés? Pero entonces en el servidor si se borraría el correcto pero de forma local no.

Hay algun tipo de "buena practica" para este tipo de problema? Noto que este codigo no es muy limpio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo algunas cosas que no cuadran en tu código:

Al parecer tu lista en el state es:

```
state = {
items_local: [
   "item numero 1", "item numero 2", "item numero 3"
]}
```

Y luego quieres pasar el `id`:

```
<div className="items-container">
        {this.state.items_local.map((item, i) =>
          <div>
            <li key={i} data-id={item.id}>{item.name}
              <button onClick={this.deleteTask.bind(this, item.id)}>Borrar</button>
            </li>
          </div>
        )}
```

Como es posible que `data-id` le asignes `item.id` cuando tu lista es de strings y no de objetos, quiero decir `item.id` será `undefined`, lo mismo al llamar al método `deleteTask`.

Yo haría lo siguiente, en vez de tener una lista de strings, o bien replicas el modelo del back o bien generas un objeto con id y value por ejemplo, algo así, te pongo un ejemplo aunque creo que ya lo tendrás mas claro.

```
state = {
  items_local: [
    { id: 1, value: 'item numero 1'},
    { id: 2, value: 'item numero 2'},
    { id: 3, value: 'item numero 3'},
    ......
  ]
}
```

Con esto creo que tu código funcionaría perfectamente, espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Buenas al final lo solucioné simplemente eliminando en el backend primero, accediendo con una funcion map al índice del id encontrado, y de esa manera me vale y no tengo que cambiar la organización del state. Aunque parece más simple tu forma, lo tendré en cuenta gracias!

Comment: Me alegro que lo solucionaras, ten en cuenta si lo haces de esa manera que puedes entrar en inconsistencia de datos ya que si eliminas un elemento y usabas su indice como id, el indice cambia y por tanto su id, saludos